# Non-cascade type menubar items not working on Tkinter with Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tkinter, menubar

I've come across what I think may be a bug where whenever I try to make a menubar (`Menu`) in tkinter on mac, any non-cascade type menu items -- that is, `menu.add_command` instead of `menu.add_cascade` -- do not appear to work.

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback():
    print("Hello World")

root = tk.Tk()

menu = tk.Menu(root)

# Adding cascade
menu2 = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu2.add_command(label="CascadeItem", command=callback)
menu.add_cascade(menu=menu2, label="Cascade")

# Adding non-cascade
menu.add_command(label="NonCascade", command=callback)

root.config(menu=menu)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run the preceding code, I am able to see the "Cascade" menu item, but not the "NonCascade" menu item.

Is there something I am doing wrong here? Is this some type of bug? Or does mac not support non-cascade type menu items on menubars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: you cannot add commands to the menubar on OSX. There is no workaround. From a usability point of view this is a bad idea, so OSX prohibits it.

Comment: I assumed this was the case. It does make sense that you cannot, but I know you can in windows so I thought I'd check. Thanks.